# Vue CLI not building subdirectory

Tags: vue.js, webpack, build

I believe I have a webpack configuration change that needs to be made by creating a vue.config file? Some guidance is appreciated.

I have this directory structure

```
src/assets/backgrounds/desktop
src/assets/backgrounds/mobile
src/assets/backgrounds/
src/assets/flags/
src/assets/fonts/
src/assets/logo/
src/assets/sounds/
```

My issue is that when I run

```
npm run build (vue-cli-service build)
```

The build doesn't create the subdirectories in the backgrounds folder.

```
src/assets/backgrounds/desktop
src/assets/backgrounds/mobile
```

I end up with a dist folder like so.

```
dist/css/
dist/img/
dist/js/
dist/media/
dist/
```

I was expecting

```
dist/img/desktop/
dist/img/mobile/
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the folowing documentation, static assets have to be put in /public folder:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling

In your case:

```
public/img/desktop/
public/img/mobile/
```

Comment: Ah thank you! It looks like I had some assets in public and some buried in src. Cheers!

Comment: @jaudo I have the same issue. If I put a video in the assets folder, the subdirectory is ignored. If I put a video in the public, in a subdirectory, the subdirectory is ignored again and appears in the root folder, even thoug Vue references the video inside public. Can you help please? Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408285/building-vue-project-ignores-media-subfolders)